# Crash if digit is more than 9

Tags: java, android, numbers

My app has an input where the user can enter a port number,I tried out of curiosity inputting more than 9 digits of number (Ex: 1234567890),and the app will crash.How do I prevent it from crashing?

**EDIT**
I am using Java language for Android

**CODING**

```
public class addActivity extends Activity{

  EditText savedName,savedIP,savedPort,savedUserID,savedUserPass,savedChannel;
  Button btnSave;
  Button btnBack;
  String addressList;
  FileOutputStream outputStream;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

savedName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editName);
savedIP = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editIP);
savedPort = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPort);
savedUserID = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userID);
savedUserPass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userPass);
savedChannel = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editChannel);
btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
btnBack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBack);


try{
     String channelNumString = savedChannel.getText().toString();
     int channelNum = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(channelNumString));

     addressList = savedName.getText().toString();

        outputStream = openFileOutput(addressList, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        //outputStream.write(savedName.getText().toString().getBytes());
        outputStream.write("4-".getBytes());
        outputStream.write(savedIP.getText().toString().getBytes());
        outputStream.write(":".getBytes());
        outputStream.write(savedPort.getText().toString().getBytes());
        outputStream.write("/user=".getBytes());
        outputStream.write(savedUserID.getText().toString().getBytes());
        outputStream.write("&password=".getBytes());
        outputStream.write(savedUserPass.getText().toString().getBytes());
        outputStream.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Address Saved !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        savedName.setText("");
        savedIP.setText("");
        savedPort.setText("");
        savedUserID.setText("");
        savedUserPass.setText("");
        savedChannel.setText("");

else{
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Apps does not support " + channelNumString + " channels",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
 }catch (Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**LAYOUT**

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editChannel"
        android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:digits="0123456789."/>
```

This is the part I'm having problem at

Comment: Which language do you use? What's your code that crashes?

Comment: Q: `How do I prevent it from crashing?` A: Don't enter more than 10 digits. I mean seriously, how can you possibly expect a better answer than that with the information you have provided?

Comment: I'm assuming this is Java based on your past questions. You will need to do some input validation, or otherwise use a `try` block. Without the code though, who knows.

Comment: @John3136,I know that answer is obvious,but it just kinda annoys me when an error like that occurs even when people are not supposed to enter more than that

Comment: @4castle,yes I am using Java,I apologize for not stating it in my question

Comment: @FayZan You've missed my point. How can we possibly tell you why code is failing when we don't have access to the code?

Comment: @John3136,I know,I apologize.I was held up when I was trying to edit the post.Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Fay Zan

Basically you don't want user to input more than 9 digits for your field,
This can be achieved using two ways programmatically or using layout views properties,

In you xml simple give this attribute to your `EditText`

```
android:maxLength="9"
```

OR programmatically by checking the length of your field. for example suppose the id of your field is `@id+/portNo`

then do validation like this

```
private EditText mportNo;
```

inside your `onCreate()`

```
mportNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.portNo);
String portValue = mportNo.getText().toString();

if(portValue.length() > 9) {
    // throw error
}
```

Comment: So simple,and yet it's perfect!Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I Assumed you are using `EditText`. so you need to use `addTextChangedListener()`.

Try the following way,

```
YOUR_EDIT_TEXT.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
          {
               public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
               public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int count, int after){} 

               public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count) 
               {
                    if(s.length() > 9)
                      {
                         //Do your stuff .
                         // You may show the intimation to user like don't try with more than 9 digits
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          //Do your stuff
                      }
               }

          });
```

This may helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,this is very good.But I prefer the answer by eLemEnt since it is simpler.I will use this code for future reference